# Applying SVG marker as additional symbol to polygon layer in QGIS 3

Tags: symbology, qgis-3, svg, categorized-renderer

I would like to add SVG markers as an additional symbol to a polygon layer.

The polygon layer is rendered with a categorized symbol renderer with different fill-color, and I want to add SVG markers to the centroid of the polygon for certain categories.

So far I only found the option "SVG Fill", is there a way to add one SVG Maker to the centroid of the polygon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the `properties` of the polygon layer, in the `symbol` tab add another symbol via the green plus and switch the new symbology's style to `centered fill`. Then change the marker to a `SVG-marker`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another solution can be achieved with `Right click on your original polygon layer -> Duplicate`.

Then simply change the new layer stylization following [@Erik](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/109646/erik)'s hints.

[image: Solution]

However, I suggest this method only for visualization purposes, e.g. when you are working with a Print Composer. Use it less for geoprocessing, since you can be easily confused about finding the primary layer and then fail with your data.

And regarding the "I want to add SVG markers to the centroid of the polygon for certain categories". I suggest applying the Rule-based symbology with Filtering those categories based on certain attributes (I believe you do have them).

[image: Rule-based_Visualization]